# TypeORM queryBuilder orderBy based on array length

Tags: typescript, postgresql, nestjs, typeorm

I have an entity which looks roughly like this

```
@Entity()
export class Post {
    @PrimaryGeneratedColumn("uuid")
    public id?: string;

    ...

    @Column("text", { default: [], array: true })
    public likes?: string[];

}
```

It has the array of likes, containing ID's of users who have liked the post.

I am using Nest, and I have a function that gets all posts. I want to order them by length of likes array, and display from the most to least.

I know it can be done by getting all posts, sorting and returing like this

```
posts.sort((a, b) => (a.likes.length < b.likes.length ? 1 : -1));
```

But as far as I'm concerned, performance-wise it would be better to order them with the queryBuilder.

The problem is, I have no clue how to achieve this, furthermore I don't know if it is even possible.

```
   const posts = await this.postsRepository
  .createQueryBuilder()
  .select("Post")
  .orderBy("Post.likes", "DESC")
  .leftJoinAndSelect("Post.author", "author")
  .leftJoinAndSelect("author.avatar", "avatar")
  .getMany();

  return posts;
```

This is what I ultimately came up with, it gets all posts, but does not order correctly

Is it possible to access something like length property in the queryBuilder? Does anyone know how to achieve this?

Any feedback would be appreciated

Comment: query builder builds sql querys, thus you'll need to write some query that counts the likes and sort by this value (or something like this. I'm not that good in SQL)

Comment: What is your database?

Comment: @omidh postgres

Comment: Honestly I don't remember. I think a possible solution here would be to store the array in JSONB column and use the `jsonb_array_length` function to obtain the length. Another solution could be creating a one to many relation instead of storing the array, and counting the number of relations